# Copying files based on File name rather than data type in Python

Tags: python, copy, filenames

I am very new to Python. I want to copy set of files from one folder to another based on the name and not based on data types. So I have a source folder with files like Hello.txt, Hello.dat, Hello.pdf, World.txt, World.dat, Word.pdf. Now I just want to copy files beginning with "Hello" into another folder. I tried many ways but all seems to be based on data type.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Comment: What ways? The obvious detections of "data type" that I can think of are, in fact, "based on file name" - they're simply looking at the end of the file name instead of the beginning. If you have "tried ways" then they shouldn't "seem" to be based on something; you should *know*. Please don't just use code that you find without first attempting to *understand* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil
files = os.listdir("Path")
for file in files:
    if file.startswith("Hello"):
       shutil.copy("Full path to file", "Full path to dest folder")
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh thanks. I used the following command to move the files using the terminal 

import os
import shutil
import glob

os.system('mv Hello.* path_to_Destination_folder')

Comment: Thanks a lot Rakesh .... I implemented it and it worked very well. Your help is highly appreciated.